# pywebkitgtk: Headless + full DOM interaction possible?

Tags: python, webkit, gtk

I am currently using the [Python Webkit DOM Bindings](http://www.gnu.org/software/pythonwebkit/) to interact with a website programmatically and that's working for me.

The only problem is that it insists on opening a GTK window to display the page. Has somebody figured out a way to prevent it from opening a window? I.e. to use it in a **headless** way?

I'm initializing the view like this:

```
    wv = pywebkitgtk.WebView(1024, 768, url=url)
```

which implicitly opens the GTK window and then I have an onload event-handler to manipulate the DOM.

I first thought of subclassing WebView, but that's not possible because it is a compiled class.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer responsible for pythonwebkit, and I have a great deal of expertise covering these areas across several platforms. Realistically, you really, really want a completely "headless" WebKit port.  In pythonwebkit that actually shouldn't be too hard to do, as there are only three "entry point" functions (one for window, one for document, and one for XMLHTTPRequest).

Really, somebody should do a proper "completely headless" port of WebKit. There already is an example program which is pretty close in WebKit's source tree, maybe that will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using PyQT. PyQTWebView runs on Webkit and works great. Check out [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) to get started, or use PyQT's API directly. Runs fully headless, and supports a decently recent build of Webkit.

Comment: I have taken a look at PyQt, but found that it doesn't offer full DOM interaction unfortunately. It has a proprietary DOM API in [QWebElement](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebelement.html) but it's not clear to me if you can get e.g. `elem.offsetWidth`, which I need. So I'd prefer to use pywebkitgtk because it implements the full DOM API. But if that's not possible I could probably use PyQT with [`evaluateJavasScript`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebelement.html#evaluateJavaScript), but that seems more like a hack.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Xvfb. I like using the command line and setting my display manually, but if you don't like that you could use this: http://cgoldberg.github.io/xvfbwrapper/

Answer (score 0):

Can you get a handle to the GTK window and then call `window.hide()`? Otherwise, you might just have to use the full Webkit library.

Comment: I haven't found a way to get the window handle unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Create a window and add the webview there, and never show the window..

I have webviews running without showing them, and can call a show_all if I need to show them.

```
web_view = pywebkitgtk.WebView()
window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow(hadjustment=None, vadjustment=None)
sw.set_policy(gtk.POLICY_NEVER, gtk.POLICY_NEVER)
sw.add(web_view)
window.add(sw)

#window.show_all()
```

Comment: I believe this only works with "standard" [pywebkitgtk](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/), but not with the [patched version](http://www.gnu.org/software/pythonwebkit/) which includes the full DOM bindings. At least if I try your example I get a TypeError. If you do have access to the DOM, I'd be interested to hear how you did it.

Comment: where do you get the error ? I do not have pywebkitgtk on this machine.

Comment: When calling `sw.add(web_view)` I get `TypeError: Gtk.Container.add() argument 1 must be gtk.Widget, not pywebkitgtk.WebView`. But as I said, I believe the problem is in the difference between standard pywebkitgtk and the patched version with the DOM bindings. If I try your code with standard pywebkitgtk (i.e. `import webkit` instead of `import pywebkitgtk`) it works fine, but I don't have access to the DOM.

Comment: okay seems like they are not creating it as a widget then hmm .. It doesn't work by just adding web_view to the window either? (remove any sw)

Comment: Doesn't work either unfortunately(same error). While playing with this code in ipython I now noticed that the the window gets opened the second you define the WebView `web_view = pywebkitgtk.WebView()`, so after that it is already too late. I also tried if any of the constructor arguments change it, but also no luck. It just seems to be baked into the class unfortunately. Thanks for your ideas anyway!